# Trying to disable Azure Security Center recommendations with policies

Tags: azure, azure-policy, securitycenter

In the ASC score recommendations, I'm trying to disable the following control. Meaning, that the security score of that control will not appear in the overall score:

**Disk encryption should be applied on virtual machines**

[Pic - Security Center recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3CMb.png)

1. I have root level policy from the Azure management (default Security Centre policy) which has the above 'Disk encryption...' policy set to enabled.
2. I created custom policy initiative->policies-> Policy: 'Disk encryption should be applied on virtual machines' -> **Disabled**.
3. tried both: custom and built-in. (they are both the same)

[Pic - Policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHxUG.png)

In the Azure Policy UI compliance - Compliant.

However, in the Azure Security Center (ASC), still no change for the above recommendation.
There are few VMs without disk encryption.

So my question, with these steps, can I increase the Security Centre score by disabling the checks for this encryption control?
and can my custom policy initiative override the existing Tenant Root Group policy?

- My initiative policy assignment is on a single subscription within the same root management tenant.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

solution: changing default ASC recommendations can be done with high level permissions on the azure policies.